# SQL Statement help : combine data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2019

I have 4 tables:

`transactions` : where the match of buy orders and sell orders in order to have a transaction

```
transaction_id (PK)| buy_order_id | sell_order_id | transaction_date        | book_name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2345               | 132          | 456           | 2022-05-16 09:02:50.867 | BOOK1
2211               | 144          | 765           | 2022-05-16 09:20:40.887 | BOOK2
2346               | 136          | 457           | 2022-05-16 10:05:10.045 | BOOK1
2212               | 155          | 766           | 2022-05-16 10:10:50.887 | BOOK2
```

`buy_orders` :

```
order_id (PK)    | placement_date          | book_name
------------------------------------------------------
132              | 2022-05-16 09:02:50.867 | BOOK1     -----> 1st match for BOOK1
133              | 2022-05-16 09:04:40.887 | BOOK1     -----> following incoming order
134              | 2022-05-16 09:05:50.887 | BOOK1
...
144              | 2022-05-16 10:10:40.887 | BOOK2
145              | 2022-05-16 10:10:50.887 | BOOK2     -----> 2nd match for BOOK2
146              | 2022-05-16 10:10:55.887 | BOOK2     -----> following incoming order
```

`sell_orders` :

```
order_id(PK)     | placement_date          | book_name
------------------------------------------------------
456              | 2022-05-16 09:00:00.867 | BOOK1     -----> 1st match for BOOK1
457              | 2022-05-16 09:02:55.887 | BOOK1     -----> following incoming order
458              | 2022-05-16 09:30:50.807 | BOOK1
...
765              | 2022-05-16 09:10:30.587 | BOOK2
766              | 2022-05-16 10:00:40.887 | BOOK2     -----> 2nd match for BOOK2
767              | 2022-05-16 10:12:55.677 | BOOK2     -----> following incoming order
```

`books` :

```
book_id (PK) | book_name
------------------------
23           | BOOK1
56           | BOOK2
```

The goal is to generate a code every time a transaction happen for a given book combining `book_name` + `transaction_id` + first incoming `order_id` (buy or sell order which came first after a transaction happened).

So, the wished output should be a single column added to tables `buy_orders` and `sell_orders` to identify the `order_book_code` to which every order belong. Every order should have an `order_book_code` that refer to the last transaction executed until another transaction execute so the `order_book_code` change.

`buy_orders UNION sell_orders`:

```
order_id (PK) | indicator  | placement_date          | book_name | order_book_code
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
456           | SELL       | 2022-05-16 09:00:00.867 | BOOK1     | BOOK1_2300_023   ----> sell before match
457           | SELL       | 2022-05-16 09:02:00.887 | BOOK1     | BOOK1_2300_023   ----> sell before match
132           | BUY        | 2022-05-16 09:02:50.867 | BOOK1     | BOOK1_2345_457   ----> match for BOOK1
133           | BUY        | 2022-05-16 09:04:40.887 | BOOK1     | BOOK1_2345_457
134           | BUY        | 2022-05-16 09:05:50.887 | BOOK1     | BOOK1_2345_457
458           | SELL       | 2022-05-16 09:30:50.807 | BOOK1     | BOOK1_2345_457

...
765           | SELL       | 2022-05-16 09:10:30.587 | BOOK2     | BOOK2_2200_100  ----> Sell before match
766           | SELL       | 2022-05-16 10:00:40.887 | BOOK2     | BOOK2_2200_100  ----> Sell before match
154           | BUY        | 2022-05-16 10:10:40.887 | BOOK2     | BOOK2_2200_100
155           | BUY        | 2022-05-16 10:10:50.887 | BOOK2     | BOOK2_2212_146  ----> match for BOOK2
156           | BUY        | 2022-05-16 10:10:55.887 | BOOK2     | BOOK2_2212_146
767           | SELL       | 2022-05-16 10:12:55.677 | BOOK2     | BOOK2_2212_146
```

I was able to collect the concerned data in my attempts but still not able to implement the logic above and combine data in one additional column :

```
SELECT p.book_name, m.transaction_id, m.transaction_date, t.order_id, t.placement_date
from books p 
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT sell_order_id, buy_order_id, transaction_id, transaction_date, book_name
FROM transactions where book_name = p.book_name ) m 
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT  'SELL' AS indicator, order_id, placement_date, book_name
from sell_orders S 
where s.order_id=m.sell_order_id 
UNION ALL SELECT 'BUY' AS indicator, order_id, placement_date, book_name
from buy_orders B 
where b.order_id=m.buy_order_id) t 
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT book_name FROM books p 
Where t.book_name = p.book_name ) f
```

How to resolve this logic in an optimal SQL statement ?

This statement was very challenging for me. I hope my explanation was clear. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: So what is your question here exactly? Where specifically in your process have you got stuck? What is your attempt so far? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Larnu. I've updated my post by mentionning the question. For the attempt, to be honest, I was spending a lot of time to implement the logic but still no success (i.e if I post my last attempt it will be so confusing to understand my logic because I was doing wrong unfortunatelly so I preferred to share with you the use cases). I also, shared an SQL statement for a step towards the goal idea. Thanks again

Comment: Firstly, changing the `UNION` to a `UNION ALL` will be a performance boost; `UNION` is a very expensive operator, and it's impossible for 2 rows in your 2 union'd statements to be the same, as you use different literal values for `indicator`.

Comment: Is the expected result that you have shown correspond to the sample data at all ? If it is not, please ensure it is the same to avoid any confusion

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Squirrel. I've revised my post.